# pandas Multiindex columns method selection returns all columns instead of subset

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Hi here is an example of behaviour I don't understand.
Here is an example of multiindex in columns

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
```

Now i'd like to select a subset of df by the first level and return the relevant columns:

```
df.loc[:, ['bar']].columns
```

returns

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

but

```
df.loc[:, ['bar', 'baz']].columns
```

returns

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

Any reason why the second one would return ALL the column names instead of

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz'], ['one', 'two']] etc...
```

And more importantly any quick fix so I can return only the relevant data?

This is made even more relevant as pandas are deprecating Panels (which used to be a very elegant way to store multidimensional data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In new pandas version (`0.20.1`) use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
print (df.loc[:, ['bar', 'baz']].columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])

print (df.loc[:, ['bar', 'baz']].columns.remove_unused_levels())
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

[Advanced shown levels in documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-shown-levels).

Comment: Thanks very much. This is a very odd behaviour imo given it doesn't behave the same for one or many.